# Privacy in simple DB system

Tags: php, mysql, database, acl, privacy

I am implementing a simple database system. Basically is a simple social network, everyone has his own dashboard, where you can post some random text. The problem is that I want a privacy level, I mean I want that somebody is allowed to browse only some profiles. And I'm deciding who can watch what.

The question is: How can I do that?I have to work with relation in the database or what?

Thanks for your time.

S.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you need exactly?  Have you tried implementing any code to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called "Access Control List" (ACL): Check out Nettuts tutorial on implementing an ACL: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/a-better-login-system/

Answer (score 0):

Create a secondary table where you keep who can access what. If in the main user table you have and id or something (preferably indexed) (like you should). Just make a 2 column table with id and view_id or something (both foreign keys and togeder should form a pk). And... you read from it.

Comment: Ok. ACL is better. He asked for a simple way. Now... what is wrong with what I suggested? Don't care about downvote but I care why is wrong?

Comment: Yah what he is trying to ask is the the simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you would want to set a table for your privacy like

```
id                 type
1            View All
2            View None
3            View Something
```

then on your table where users can be found you could call the type

```
user_id    privacy_id 
1            2
2            3
4            1
```

where privacy_id is the id of your privacy table, something like that.

Comment: downvote, don't need it any way you can downvote all you want

Comment: looks valid to me. why done vote it? with the note that there should be one more column at second table. mine is valid also